# Numerical solution of the stationary Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, applications

Let $d\le 3$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain. I'm considering an incompressible Newtonian fluid with uniform density $\rho_0$ and viscosity $\nu$. In this case, the *stationary Navier-Stokes equations* are $$\left\{\begin{matrix}(u\cdot\nabla)u&=&\displaystyle\nu\Delta u-\frac 1\rho_0\nabla p+f&&\text{in }\Omega\\\nabla\cdot u&=&0&&\text{in }\Omega\\u&=&0&&\text{on }\partial\Omega\end{matrix}\right.\;,\tag 1$$ where $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R^d$ is the sum of all external forces.

---

Assuming $d=1$ for simplicity, the so-called *Oseen-iteration* is given by $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\displaystyle u^{(n-1)}\frac{du^{(n)}}{dx}&=&\displaystyle\nu\frac{d^2u^{(n)}}{dx^2}-\frac 1\rho_0\frac{dp^{(n)}}{dx}+f^{(n)}&&\text{in }\Omega\\\displaystyle\frac{du^{(n)}}{dx}&=&0&&\text{in }\Omega\\u^{(n)}&=&0&&\text{on }\partial\Omega\end{matrix}\right.\;.\tag 2$$ Using $$\frac{dg}{dx}(x)\approx\frac{g(x+\Delta)-g(x-\Delta)}{2\Delta}\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}(x)\approx\frac{g(x+\Delta)-2g(x)+g(x-\Delta)}{\Delta^2}$$ we're left with a system of linear equations: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\displaystyle u_{k}^{(n-1)}\left(u_{k+1}^{(n)}-_{k-1}^{(n)}\right)&=&\displaystyle\frac{2\nu}\Delta\left(u_{k+1}^{(n)}-2u_{k}^{(n)}+u_{k-1}^{(n)}\right)-\frac 1\rho_0\left(p_{k+1}^{(n)}-p_{k-1}^{(n)}\right)+2\Delta f_k\\\displaystyle\frac{u_{k+1}^{(n)}-u_{k-1}^{(n)}}{2\Delta}&=&0\\u_k^{(n)}&=&0\end{matrix}\right.\;,\tag 3$$ where $x_k=k\Delta$, $g_k:=g(x_k)$ and the equations need to hold for $k$ with $x_k\in\Omega$ or $x_k\in\partial\Omega$, respectively. However, as you may have already observed, the second equation is equivalent to $$u_{k+1}^{(n)}=u_{k-1}^{(n)}\;\;\;\text{for }x_k\in\Omega\;.$$ Thus, the first equation can be simplified to $$0=\frac{4\nu}\Delta\left(u_{k+1}^{(n)}-u_{k}^{(n)}\right)-\frac 1\rho_0\left(p_{k+1}^{(n)}-p_{k-1}^{(n)}\right)+2\Delta f_k\;\;\;\text{for }x_k\in\Omega\;.$$

---

Hence, the $u_{k}^{(n-1)}$ of the corresponding previous iteration are gone. Did I made any mistake? Since the $u_{k}^{(n-1)}$ are gone, there is no "iteration" anymore.

Comment: If $d=1$, the first equation is a _linear_ differential equation, and your iteration has to be restated. For $d \ge 2$, $\text{div }u = 0$ is not going to cancel the $n-1$ term of the iteration. Basically, what you are doing is treating the nonlinearity as a "right hand term" (i.e. first solve the linear problem, then substitute the nonlinearity, then solve the new linear problem, and so on). If there isn't a nonlinearity, there isn't a need for iteration (or new iteration needed).

Comment: @Pragabhava It seems like you're right. In this case, I would like to consider $d=2$. My real question is: How can I write $(3)$ in the form $Ax=b$? Since you've basically answered *this* question, I've asked another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566512/how-can-i-write-the-linear-system-of-equations-given-by-the-oseen-iteration-in-t

Comment: What do yo expect $A$ and $b$ be? Funcions of $u$? Constants?

Comment: @Pragabhava I expect that $A$ and $b$ are constants. Isn't it the whole point of *Oseen-iteration* that one only needs to solve a linear system of equations in each iteration?

Comment: As stated, $A$ will be a function of the previous step.$$\left(u_k^{n-1} - \frac{2\nu}{\Delta}\right)u_{k+1}^n + \frac{4\nu}{\Delta} u_k^n - \left(u_k^{n-1} + \frac{2\nu}{\Delta}\right)u_{k-1}^n = -\frac{1}{\rho_0}\left(p_{k+1}^n - p_{k-1}^n\right) + 2\Delta f_k$$ Then $A$ will be the tridiagonal matrix whose $k$-th row is $$(A)_k = (0 \quad \cdots \quad \underbrace{-u_k^{n-1} - \frac{2\nu}{\Delta}}_{k-1} \quad \underbrace{\frac{4\nu}{\Delta}}_k \quad \underbrace{u_k^{n-1} - \frac{2\nu}{\Delta}}_{k+1} \quad \cdots \quad 0)$$

Comment: @Pragabhava That $A$ will depend on the previous step is clear. But in each iteration we can assume that $A$ is constant since we know the values calculated in the previous step. I assume you refer to ("as stated") equation $(3)$ in *this* question. I'm more interested in $(3)$ of the other (linked) question and want to find $A$ and $b$ and the form of $x$ in that case.

Comment: I meant $A$ constant in the sense that it doesn't depend on $u$ at all (it's a discreet system, everything that's not the variable, is a constant). If you write the nonlinear term as $(u^{n-1}\nabla)u^{n-1}$ instead of $(u^{n-1}\nabla)u^n$, then $A$ will be the standard Rayleigh matrix, and $b$ _will_ depend on the previous step. My guess is that both methods will converge relatively well, but the second is deemed to be significatively faster. Don't forget you'll have to invert $A$ at each step for the first method.

Comment: @Pragabhava Since I've still got problems to implement this, I've created a more specific question (All good things go by threes): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569481/implementation-of-a-simulation-of-an-incompressible-newtonian-fluid-with-uniform