# Implementation of a simulation of an incompressible Newtonian fluid with uniform density

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

Let $d\in\left\{2,3\right\}$ and $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain. I want to simulate an incompressible Newtonian fluid with uniform density $\rho$ and viscosity $\nu$.

The evolution up to time $T>0$ of such a fluid is given by the *instationary Navier-Stokes equations* $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\displaystyle\left(\frac\partial{\partial t}+\boldsymbol u\cdot\nabla\right)\boldsymbol u&=&\displaystyle\nu\Delta\boldsymbol u-\frac 1\rho\nabla p+\boldsymbol f&&\text{in }\Omega\times (0,T)\\\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol u&=&0&&\text{in }\Omega\times (0,T)\end{matrix}\right.\;,\tag 1$$ where $\boldsymbol u:\Omega\times [0,T]\to\mathbb R^d$ and $p:\Omega\times [0,T]\to\mathbb R$ are the *velocity* field and *pressure* we're looking for and $\boldsymbol f:\Omega\times (0,T)\to\mathbb R^d$ is the sum of all external forces.

> Suppose we're given $\boldsymbol u_0=\boldsymbol u(\;\cdot\;,0)$ and $p_0=p(\;\cdot\;,0)$. How do we obtain $\boldsymbol u_\tau$ and $p_\tau$ for some delta time $\tau\in (0,T)$?

---

Let's restrict the question to $d=2$. Using the *implicit Euler method*, we need to solve the *stationary* problem $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\displaystyle\frac{\boldsymbol u_\tau-\boldsymbol u_0}\tau+\left(\boldsymbol u_\tau\cdot\nabla\right)\boldsymbol u_\tau&=&\displaystyle\nu\Delta\boldsymbol u_\tau-\frac 1\rho\nabla p_\tau+\boldsymbol f_\tau&&\text{in }\Omega\\\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol u_\tau&=&0&&\text{in }\Omega\end{matrix}\right.\;.\tag 2$$ This problem can be numerically solved using a *Oseen iteration*: $$\left\{\begin{matrix}\displaystyle\frac{\boldsymbol u_\tau^{(n)}-\boldsymbol u_0}\tau+\left(\boldsymbol u_\tau^{(n-1)}\cdot\nabla\right)\boldsymbol u_\tau^{(n)}&=&\displaystyle\nu\Delta\boldsymbol u_\tau^{(n)}-\frac 1\rho\nabla p_\tau^{(n)}+\boldsymbol f_\tau&&\text{in }\Omega\\\nabla\cdot \boldsymbol u_\tau^{(n)}&=&0&&\text{in }\Omega\end{matrix}\right.\;.\tag 3$$

---

Let's draw our attention to a simple example: Let

- $\boldsymbol u=(u,v)$ and $\boldsymbol f=(f,g)$
- $\Omega=(a,b)\times (c,d)$, $$x_i:=a+i\Delta x\;\;\;\text{for }i=0,\ldots,m:=\frac{b-a}{\Delta x}$$ and $$y_j:=c+j\Delta y\;\;\;\text{for }j=0,\ldots,n:=\frac{d-c}{\Delta y}$$
- $\varphi^{ij}:=\varphi(x_i,y_j)$ for any function $\varphi$ defined on $\Omega$

Using $$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}(x,y)\approx\frac{\varphi(x+h,y)-\varphi(x-h,y)}{2\Delta x}$$ and $$\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x^2}(x,y)\approx\frac{\varphi(x+h,y)-2\varphi(x,y)+\varphi(x-h,y)}{{\Delta x}^2}$$ (you can imagine how we approximate $\partial/\partial y$ and $\partial^2/\partial y^2$) we obtain a system

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left(\frac{{\Delta x}^2{\Delta y}^2}\tau+4\nu\left({\Delta x}^2+{\Delta y}^2\right)\right)\color{red}{\tilde u_\tau^{ij}}&+{\Delta y}^2\left(\Delta xu_\tau^{ij}-2\nu\right)\color{red}{\tilde u_\tau^{(i+1)j}}\\&-{\Delta y}^2\left(\Delta x u_\tau^{ij}+2\nu\right)\color{red}{\tilde u_\tau^{(i-1)j}}\\&+{\Delta x}^2\left(\Delta y v_\tau^{ij}-2\nu\right)\color{red}{\tilde u_\tau^{i(j+1)}}\\&-{\Delta x}^2\left(\Delta y v_+^{ij}+2\nu\right)\color{red}{\tilde u_\tau^{i(j-1)}}\\&+\frac{\Delta x{\Delta y}^2}\rho\color{blue}{\tilde p_\tau^{(i+1)j}}\\&-\frac{\Delta x{\Delta y}^2}\rho\color{blue}{\tilde p_\tau^{(i-1)j}}=\frac{2{\Delta x}^2{\Delta y}^2}\tau u_0^{ij}+2{\Delta x}^2{\Delta y}^2f_\tau^{ij}\\
\left(\frac{{\Delta x}^2{\Delta y}^2}\tau+4\nu\left({\Delta x}^2+{\Delta y}^2\right)\right)\color{green}{\tilde v_\tau^{ij}}&+{\Delta y}^2\left(\Delta xu_\tau^{ij}-2\nu\right)\color{green}{\tilde v_\tau^{(i+1)j}}\\&-{\Delta y}^2\left(\Delta x u_\tau^{ij}+2\nu\right)\color{green}{\tilde v_\tau^{(i-1)j}}\\&+{\Delta x}^2\left(\Delta y v_\tau^{ij}-2\nu\right)\color{green}{\tilde v_\tau^{i(j+1)}}\\&-{\Delta x}^2\left(\Delta y v_+^{ij}+2\nu\right)\color{green}{\tilde v_\tau^{i(j-1)}}\\&+\frac{{\Delta x}^2\Delta y}\rho\color{blue}{\tilde p_\tau^{(i+1)j}}\\&-\frac{{\Delta x}^2\Delta y}\rho\color{blue}{\tilde p_\tau^{(i-1)j}}=\frac{2{\Delta x}^2{\Delta y}^2}\tau v_0^{ij}+2{\Delta x}^2{\Delta y}^2g_\tau^{ij}\\
\frac{1}{2\Delta x}\color{red}{\tilde u_\tau^{(i+1)j}}-\frac{1}{2\Delta x}\color{red}{\tilde u_\tau^{(i-1)j}}&=-\frac{1}{2\Delta y}\color{green}{\tilde v_\tau^{i(j+1)}}+\frac{1}{2\Delta y}\color{green}{\tilde v_\tau^{i(j-1)}}
\end{split}\tag 4
\end{equation}

of $(d+1)(m-1)(n-1)$ linear equations (and just as many unknows), where I've written $\tilde\varphi$ instead of $\varphi^{(n)}$ and $\varphi$ instead of $\varphi^{(n-1)}$, for $\varphi\in\left\{u,v,p\right\}$, in order to beautify the notation.

If we introduce the more suitable indexing $$k\equiv i(n+1)+j\;\;\;\text{for }i=0,\ldots,m\text{ and }j=0,\ldots,n\;,$$ we're able to write $(4)$ in the form $$Ax=b\;.\tag 5$$

---

> However, I'm unsure whether or not my attempt so far is sensible or not. Moreover, $A$ in $(5)$ is sparse and somehow regular, but it's still not easy to implement a solver.
>
> To be explicit: Given $d=2$ and $\Omega=(a,b)\times (c,d)$, I want to implement a simple solver for $(5)$. How can I do so? How should I generate $A$ and $b$? Should I use a Gauss–Seidel iteration to solve $(5)$? And how would such an iteration look like algorithmically?

Comment: If it's not clear enough: The "unknows" are the values of $u_\tau$, $v_\tau$ and $p_\tau$ at the "inner" grid points. Moreover, you can assume that the values of these quantities at the boundary grid points are given.

Comment: What you've done is just a standard first-order implicit central-differencing scheme. What language are you going to write your code in? In Matlab, you can just use `A\b` to solve the matrix problem. The matrix `M` isn't too hard to generate, `diag` will be useful, just look at some examples. You need to include your boundary conditions in the matrix problem as well.

Comment: @David I need to write the code in C++ and I don't want to use an external library.

Comment: I don't really know anything about C++, but I'm suer you'll need some kind of linear algebra/math libraries. If you can write the matrix problem you need to solve down on paper, it should be easy enough to code up. Maybe you should start with a simple PDE rather than the Navier-Stokes equations for your first time doing numerics?

Comment: @David This is not my first time doing numerics ;) And I don't want to solve the Navier-Stokes equations cause they are interesting PDEs, but because I need to simulate a fluid. I wasn't sure, if my approach is sensible or not. (and I'm aware of the literature in CFD. I just want to look what *I* can achieve with simple considerations).

Comment: Yeah your approach is fine, it's a standard way of solving PDEs numerically. The trouble may be getting enough resolution and accuracy without using too much time and memory, but that depends on the problem you're trying to solve. You'll also want to think about your CFL number to ensure stability, which will be important. It's hard to say much more really. Also think about whether you can simplify the N-S equations, do you have small viscosity, a particular shaped domain or anything, something like that would make it a lot easier so is worth thinking about.

Comment: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-29-numerical-fluid-mechanics-fall-2011/lecture-notes/MIT2_29F11_lect_24.pdf

Comment: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S1064827593244213

Comment: http://www.fem.unicamp.br/~phoenics/SITE_PHOENICS/Apostilas/CFD-1_U%20Michigan_Hong/Lecture13.pdf